# Sorting odd and even numbers with the remainder operator Javascript

Tags: javascript

If a number, when divided by two, has a remainder that is not equal to 0, this number must be odd. I'm trying to use that logic in my if statement to keep only odd values, and get rid of even ones. I'm not sure how I'm doing this wrong, but myArray is returning even values as well as odd. Any ideas?

```
function sumFibs(num) {
  var myArray = [1,1];
  // Create fibonacci sequence
  // Stop creating fibonacci numbers at num
  // Push odd numbers to oddNums array
  for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {

    if (myArray[i+1] + myArray[i] <= num && myArray[i+1] + myArray[i] % 2 !== 0) {
      myArray.push(myArray[i+1] + myArray[i]);
    }
  } // End loop.

  console.log(myArray);
  // Summation of oddNums array.
  return myArray.reduce(function(a,b) {
    return a + b;
  });
} // End function.

sumFibs(1000);
```

Comment: Why not just use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)?

Comment: Also you should probably use parentheses around `myArray[i+1] + myArray[i]`, like this: `(myArray[i+1] + myArray[i]) % 2 !== 0`.

Comment: Looks like a problem with operator precendence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to filter odd values while generating your fib sequence, which probably not the best approach.  If you wrap the modulo expression in parentheses,

```
(myArray[i+1] + myArray[i]) % 2
```

Your array will not contain the values necessary to continue generating the sequence.  Ideally you should generate the full fib series and then filter:

```
var myArray = [1,1];
for (var i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
  myArray.push(myArray[i+1] + myArray[i]);
} // End loop.
myArray = myArray.filter(function(a){ return a%2 !== 0 })
```

or save some reference to the even values so that they can be used to calculate the desired subset of the series.

Comment: Right, generate the full series then filter. This approach worked. Thanks for posting. I should note that to return only odd numbers I should return {a%2 !== 0}. I'll try to edit that into your post.

Comment: Nice catch, sorry I typed that without proofing.